# Showing a collection of half open intervals generate a borel sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H} = \{ (a, \infty) : a \in \mathbb{R} \} $. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be borel sigma algebra generated by the family of open sets. I have already shown that $\mathcal{B}$ is also generated by open intervals. Now I want to show that $\sigma( \mathcal{H} ) = \mathcal{B} $.

#### TRY:

We know intervals of the form $(a, \infty) $ are open sets. Hence, $\mathcal{H} \subseteq \mathcal{B} $ and so $\sigma( \mathcal{H} ) \subseteq \mathcal{B} $

If $\mathcal{I}$ is the collection of all intervals of the form $(a,b]$, we have shown in my class that $\sigma( \mathcal{I} ) = \mathcal{B} $. Consequently, if we can show that $\sigma( \mathcal{I} ) \subset \sigma( \mathcal{H} ) $, then we are done, and to do this it is enough to show that $\mathcal{I} \subset \sigma( \mathcal{H} )$. But this follows since we know

$$(a,b] =  (a, \infty) \cap (b, \infty)^c$$

Is this a correct solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a correct solution. However, I recommend writing it up in the other direction and in an assertive manner. Maybe like so:

Since for all $a < b$ we have $(a,b] = (a,+\infty) \cap (b,+\infty)^c \in \sigma(\mathcal{H})$. It follows that $\mathcal{I} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{H})$, and hence $\sigma(\mathcal{I}) \subset \sigma(\mathcal{H})$. By [cite lecture] we know that $\mathcal{B} = \sigma(\mathcal{I})$, thus $\mathcal{B}\subset \sigma(\mathcal{H}) \subset \mathcal{B}$, q.e.d.